# Diversity index between 0 and 1 for different proportions

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I would like to come up with a measure of how diverse the population is.
I have 3 groups of people:
White, Black, Chinese. Let $\pi_i$ denote the proportions of the total population e.g. $$\pi_\text{white}=\frac{\text{white}}{\text{white}+\text{black}+\text{chinese}}$$

I want to come up with a measure to see how diverse a population is. This meanse that if $$\pi_\text{white}=\pi_\text{black}=\pi_\text{chinese}=\frac{1}{3}$$ we let $d=1$ (diversity)

However if $$\pi_\text{white}=1,\pi_\text{black}=\pi_\text{chinese}=0$$ the diversity $d=0$.

You can smooth out the line in any way possible.

**Edit:**
I'm thinking of a function $f(\pi_i)$ which peaks at 0.33 for $f(0.33)$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Then I can define the diversity measure to be $\sum_i f(\pi_i)$. What would this function be? Something that looks like $f(x)=-x(x-1)$, but with a different maxima.
Also I'd like to generalise it and do it for $n$ categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want (information theoretical) entropy

$$H = \sum -\pi_i \log(\pi_i)$$

That has a maximum when all of the $\pi_i$'s are equal, and approaches zero as one of the $\pi_i$s heads to $1$ and the others head towards $0$. The maximum is $\log(n)$, so you'll have to divide by that to get the normalization you want.

(Notes: Since you'll be normalizing it doesn't matter what base you use for your $\log$s, though it's traditionally log base 2 in info. theory. Also, if one of the $\pi_i$ equals $0$ it contributes $0$ to the sum, which is consistent with $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x\log x = 0$.)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I need. I'll try it out

Comment: By the way, having thought more about it, you might want to skip the normalization step. I'd say that a population evenly divided among four groups is more diverse than one evenly divided among three, and you'd lose that difference if you normalize. So just the raw entropy might work better for you.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's a good point and it would fit better